# Post to twitter with applescript

Tags: twitter, applescript

I´m broadcasting hockey with wirecast and use applescripts triggered by a usb-controller to create replays, highlights etc. I need as much as possible of what I´m doing to be automated as I am alone working with this witch means I´m also the cameraman :)

Now I want to be able to convert and upload a .gif of the last scored goal. So far I have been able to convert my .mov file to .gif but haven´t found a way to upload it to twitter.

The workflow is: when a team scores a goal I push a button on my usb-controller. This stops wirecast-recording, opens the recorded file in quicktime player 7, trims it down to the last 16 seconds and when that file is finished playing it saves as .mov and converts to .gif.

Here is where I run into trouble. I have been able to make twitter posts by using https://ifttt.com but it dosen´t seem to suport uploading .gif files. If I manually upload the .gif on twitter.com it works. What I need is to make it automated.

Anyone have ideas of how to do this? I´m pretty new to scripting and really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems like I was doing it right from the start but my .gif was to large (11.5 Mb). I made it shorter and with less frames (1.8 Mb) and now it posts as it should when using ifttt.com. Thank you Björn :)